# How to customize Mac TextMate keyboard shortcuts with a "copy current line" command?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, textmate

I would like to be able to click on a line of text without selecting it, and use a keyboard shortcut to copy all text on the current line. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest thing to that is ⇧⌘L followed by ⌘C.

Comment: You could use the Macro Editor to save this sequence (Bundles > Macros > Start Recording) and give it a key combination. Works like a charm. (Just make sure you **uncheck** the "use local clipboard while executing macro" option at the bottom of the macro in the Bundle editor.)

Comment: Thanks to the macro tip! Given the awesomeness of TextMate, I can't say that one simple macro inconveniences me!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this helps but another useful one is Ctrl+Shift+D which will take the current line and duplicate it right below.

Answer (score 0):

To have that in all standard text views, create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` that looks like:

```
{
    "^~c" = ("selectParagraph:", "copy:"); // ⌃⌥C
}
```

For more info, see [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html).

Some of TextMate's text editing shortcuts are defined in a similar property list file at `/path/to/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict`. Modifications should be made to a copy in `Application Support` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emacs bindings. Most Mac apps support them. Control-k (kill) cuts the line to the emacs equivalent of a pasteboard and control-y (yank) pastes the results back. This pasteboard is different from the regular Mac pasteboard and with TextMate only appears to work with one window. If you control-k then control-y it is the equivalent of copy.